# How do I stop an image displaying outside of the div

Tags: html, css

Consider this code...

```
<div id="outer" style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black">
  <div id="inner">
    <img src="http://rabbitempire.org/wp-content/uploads/Pet-Rabbit-Facts.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

What style(s) do I need to add to make it so only the top left hand corner of the image is visible?

Please note, I don;t want to use a background image because the question is really about divs, believe it or not but the rabbit isn't part of my application. Oh and in "real life" I wouldn't use inline css.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
div#outer { overflow:hidden; }​
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/J34aJ/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but where did the rabbit go?

Comment: @tomwrong: Initially, in my haste, I thought you had included some local image you were working with (and not something publicly hosted), so I was using http://placehold.it/ as a placeholder.

Answer (score 20):

You can just apply `img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }` to image tag

Comment: This is the best solution out there

Answer (score 3):

You can lose the `#inner` div and add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#outer` div.

```
#outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as this:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

re-write your outer div style to apply `overflow:hidden`

```
<div id="outer" style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black; overflow:hidden;">
      <div id="inner">
        <img src="http://rabbitempire.org/wp-content/uploads/Pet-Rabbit-Facts.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to your `#outer` rule: http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/qJWte/

```
<div id="outer" style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black; overflow: none">
  <div id="inner">
    <img src="http://rabbitempire.org/wp-content/uploads/Pet-Rabbit-Facts.jpg">
  </div>
</div>​
```