# Automatically resize images to a div like in Reddit

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am creating a Reddit clone, and resizing images is the hardest part of my Post component.

**The Problem:**

I am fetching random images with different sizes and different available resolutions, some Images look distorted, are too wide, too tall or just don't fit well in my div.

If you look at [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/coolguides/), you will notice that images fit perfectly, wide images fit the div and look great, tall images aren't that tall, etc. I would like to resize images to fit my component.

**My Clone Post:**

[image: Overly wide image]

**Reddit Post:**

[image: Well Sized Image]

Both posts have almost the same width, but in mine the image overflows outside the div. I want it to fit perfectly like in Reddit.

The post width is 720px.

**The Fetched Image Object:**

```
    {
  "preview": {
    "enabled": true,
    "images": [
      {
        "id": "z4bvHMwOJQpsudypcyuMTkFVQjEw6eVlhNiSbfcnW5c",
        "resolutions": [
          {
            "url": "https://preview.redd.it/t2neopha4fv91.jpg?width=10…bp&amp;s=333b2cd177a9756ef8024b645f55ece666dc6a61",
            "width": 108,
            "height": 133
          },
          {
            "url": "https://preview.redd.it/t2neopha4fv91.jpg?width=21…bp&amp;s=bb6c964f63592c67ee747ea4f6a67ab997423be2",
            "width": 216,
            "height": 266
          },
          {
            "url": "https://preview.redd.it/t2neopha4fv91.jpg?width=32…bp&amp;s=410ac13c1862010bfe90b5ab7b78f09d9059a730",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 394
          },
          {
            "url": "https://preview.redd.it/t2neopha4fv91.jpg?width=64…bp&amp;s=128216dd3d1b6f4c1447a6c32e2188d5a54ca460",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 789
          },
          {
            "url": "https://preview.redd.it/t2neopha4fv91.jpg?width=96…bp&amp;s=a1139ec38b71d6d732dcab998e55829c26efa89a",
            "width": 960,
            "height": 1183
          },
          {
            "url": "https://preview.redd.it/t2neopha4fv91.jpg?width=10…bp&amp;s=3ccf13630ed47a71c66b84d720abcba324745eb2",
            "width": 1080,
            "height": 1331
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "source": {
      "height": 1386,
      "url": "https://preview.redd.it/t2neopha4fv91.jpg?auto=webp&amp;s=bc87cbeb0c0b1e078649e49d4b472f8b34555a5b",
      "width": 1124
    }
  }
}
```

The fetched preview object has a main source image, and the same image but with different resolutions. (P.D. in the image's URL I replaced the 'amp;' with '', if not you won't be able to use them).

**The Image In React**

```
   <img 
       src={post.preview.images[0].source.url.replace(/amp;/, "")}
       alt={post.preview.images[0].id}
       className="postImage"
       style={{
           width: post.preview.images[0].source.width /2,
           height: post.preview.images[0].source.height /2
       }}
   />
```

***Keep in mind that I'm fetching a lot of images with different proportions, so I've got to create a solution that fits all.***

Comment: Maybe watch this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726238/how-do-i-stop-an-image-displaying-outside-of-the-div

Comment: @Asmoth thanks for commenting, I don't want to crop the image I want it to smartly resize to fit the div.

Comment: `width: 100%` will size an image to 100% of the parents width. So just wrap the image with a block level element...